# Where are Adobe Acrobat Pro settings saved

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to figure out where the settings and options of an application(Adobe Acrobt Pro) are saved.  This is to modify the settings without opening the application and going through the menu options.  I'm trying to change the resolution of TIF settings.

I have looked in the program file acrobat folder and the documents and settings but haven't found it.  I also looked through the registry entrees just to make sure but didn't see anything relevant.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the acquire function in Acrobat, it's in the registry under:
`HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\X.0\Scan\cScanerValues\` in a key named similar to `[ScannerModel]Resolution`

Be sure to substitute X.0 for the verion, like 9.0 or whatever. Also, you must have scanned something in at least once for the settings to appear there.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), make the changes via the adobe menu options then stop the capture. If you look through the entries corresponding to the acrobat process name it will tell you what file & registry writes were done.

Comment: thanks i was looking for something to monitor the changes.  I will give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Looking at the events it doesn't look like the TIF setting changes are being captured with the Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state the Operating System.

Assuming 7 / Vista,

```
C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat\9.0\Preferences
```

or

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat\9.0\Preferences
```

On XP

```
C:\Users\User_Name\Application Data\Adobe\Acrobat\9.0\Preferences
```

or

```
%userprofile%\Application Data\Adobe\Acrobat\9.0\Preferences
```

(First lines is actual, replace User_Name with your username, or second lines will work on any machine)

Comment: Scanner settings are in the registry, not in those files.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat stores an enormous amount of data in the registry.
(By enormous I mean thousands of entries!!!)

I assume that what you're looking for is included among this oceanic amount of data. Using a utility such as Process Monitor to trace it out would be excruciatingly painful.

You could rather use a product such as [InstallRite 2.5](http://www.epsilonsquared.com/) to create a snapshot of the registry before and after making that change, and report only the differences.